# Is $\Bbb{Q}[F]$ a field whenever $F$ is a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, group-rings

Let $F = $ a finite field for example.  Let $\Bbb{Q}[F]$ be a field ring, which is similar to a group ring except you have both operations extended homomorphically to the whole space, so that distributivity occurs naturally and you have a ring.

But we chose $\Bbb{Q}$ as our coefficient ring.  Is $\Bbb{Q}[F]$ a field?  It's sort of like a finite extension when $F$ is finite!  Interesting.  Since we're not declaring a parent space.

---

What both operations extended homorphically to all of $\Bbb{Z}[F]$ means is this:

$a = \sum_{f \in F} a_f f,  \ b = \sum_{f \in F} b_f f$

Then since $\cdot$ and $+$ are homomorphic in each argument (via extending ring-homomorphically), we have:

$$
a + b = \sum_{f \in F} (a_f + b_f) f \\
a\cdot b = \sum_{f \in F} \sum_{gh = f} (a_gb_h) f
$$

Similar to standard group ring stuff.

Comment: "you have both operations extended homomorphically to the whole space" what does that mean?

Comment: For $G$ cyclic (non-trivial) the group ring is $\Bbb{Q}[G]\cong \Bbb{Q}[x]/(x^{|G|}-1)$ which is never an integral domain (as $(x-1)(\sum_{j=0}^{|G|-1} x^j) = 0$). I don't see what alternative structure you can think to.

Comment: @reuns not quite sure how that applies since $\Bbb{Q}[R^{\cdot}] \mapsto +$ and $\Bbb{Q}[R^+] \mapsto +$ in another usually separate structure.  So we have rings here.  I'm not seeing how your statement applies is all.

Comment: What is the element $0_F$ supposed to be in this ring? Is it just $0$? In that case, you seem to get $\mathbb{Q}F^\times$, which is the group algebra described by @reuns.

Comment: @DavidHill $0_{\Bbb{Q}[F]} = \sum_{f \in F} 0 f$ a formal sum.

Comment: Your definition at the end appears to be the definition of the monoid ring of the multiplicative monoid of $F$, so it is entirely unclear how you intend the "field ring" to be different.

Comment: @EricWofsey forgot some parts.

Comment: The element $0_F\in F$. What is $1\cdot 0_F\in\mathbb{Q}[F]$?

Comment: It sounds like what you're really trying to define is the tensor product $\mathbb{Q}\otimes F$.  This will always be just the zero ring if $F$ is finite though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $F$ is a finite field of cardinality $p$. Assume that $\mathbb Q[F]$ is a field. Then $\mathbb Q[F]$ contains all $(p-1)$th roots of unity.

Also, $\mathbb Q$ embeds in $\mathbb Q[F]$, by the map $q \mapsto q \cdot 1_F$. Hence it is a number field of degree $p$. But it contains $\zeta_{p-1}$, so it contains a field of degree $\varphi(p-1)$. Hence $\varphi(p-1) \mid p$. This is not possible for $p \geq 5$.

Comment: What about $p=2,3$?

Comment: See the other answers.

Comment: I did and I liked your first answer better and upvoted it. I’d upvote this one of you worked out the $p=2$ and $p=3$ cases explicitly.

Answer (score 4):

The definition of $\mathbb Q[F]$ does not depend on the addition of $F$, so it is the monoid ring $\mathbb Q[F]$ where $F$ is considered as a multiplicative monoid.

The element $0_F \in \mathbb Q[F]$ is nonzero, and it has the property that $0_F^2 = 0_F$.

Likewise, the element $1_F$ is nonzero and satisfies $1_F^2 = 1_F$.

But a field cannot have two nonzero idempotents.

Comment: How is $0_F$ nonzero?

Comment: It is the formal sum $\sum a_f f$ with $a_f = 1$ for $f = 0$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: $a_f = 0$ for all

Comment: @ShineOnYouCrazyDiamond: No, that's the zero of the ring; it is not the formal element $0_F$.

Answer (score 1):

So the OP wanted to define, with $M$ the multiplicative monoid of $\Bbb{F}_q$, the monoid ring $$k[M]=k[ \Bbb{F}_q^*\cup 0]\cong k[x,z]/(x^{q-1}-1,z^2-z, xz-z)$$
where $x$ is thought as a generator of $\Bbb{F}_q^\times$ and $z$ is thought as $0\in \Bbb{F}_q$.

It is never an integral domain because it contains $k[x]/(x^{q-1}-1)$ and $(x-1)(\sum_{j=0}^{q-2}x^j-1)=0$, and for $q=2$ it is because it contains the non-zero idempotent element $z$ which is not $1$ because $xz\ne x$.

Comment: do you mean to say let $q = $ a prime number?

Comment: You said a finite field so $q=p^k$, but any $q$ gives a similar $k[M]$. If your field is infinite then there is still the $z$ non-zero idempotent  non-unit stuff.

Comment: About the infinite cyclic group case : note that $k[\Bbb{Z}]\cong k[t,t^{-1}]$ is an integral domain.